# Convert list of sentences to list of word tokens

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I have a list as below

```
data_corpus = ["John likes to watch movies",
 "Mary likes movies too", 
"John also likes to watch football games"]
```

I want to get

```
['John', 'likes', 'to', 'watch', 'movies', 'Mary', 'likes', 'movies', 'too',
 'John', 'also', 'likes', 'to', 'watch', 'football', 'games']
```

I do

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
tokenized = [word_tokenize(i) for i in data_corpus]
tokenized
```

ang get list of sentences instead of list of words

```
[['John', 'likes', 'to', 'watch', 'movies'],
 ['Mary', 'likes', 'movies', 'too'],
 ['John', 'also', 'likes', 'to', 'watch', 'football', 'games']]
```

How to fix it?

Comment: In your case an option could be `list(chain.from_iterable(map(word_tokenize, data_corpus)))`.

Comment: Try `word_tokenize('\n'.join(data_corpus))`